# 64 bit subtraction without using asm sub and sbb?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, pascal

I have a question, how to realize 64 bit subtraction of 2 nums without using asm commands sub and sbb? c flag must be changed in process to show carry from one register to other! I use Free Pascal IDE and built-in Intel style assembler.
So here's what I did:

```
//1 number
mov esi, 0f000000h //low part
mov edi, 0         //high part
//2 number
mov ecx, 0f000000h //l
mov edx, 0         //h
//neg 2 num
neg ecx            //0f1000000h -> ecx
neg edx
//1 num l part + (- 2 num l part)
add esi, ecx       //0 -> esi, c=1!
//c -> eax
mov eax, 0
lahf
mov al, ah
mov ah, 0
and al, 1
neg eax            //0ffffffffh -> eax
//1 num h part + (- 2 num h part)
add edi, edx
//1 num h part + (- c flag)
add edi, eax       //0ffffffffh -> edi, s flag = 1
//verify result    
mov esi, 0f000000h
mov edi, 0
mov ecx, 0f000000h
mov edx, 0
sub esi, ecx //c=0!
sbb edi, edx
```

When I'm trying to verify result using sub and sbb it's correct and logical but not equal to above. So what I'm doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: You can't negate a 64-bit number by using `neg` on the high and low dwords separately. Instead do the `not; not; add; adc` thing.

Comment: Why not use `setc` instead of that convoluted `lahf`-thing? Must this be able to run on pre-80386 hardware?

Comment: Why do this at all since both sub and sbb *are* supported, and quite efficiently, on all x86 platforms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't `NEG` both parts of the number and expect a correct result. Example: `-1`=`0xFFFFFFFF 0xFFFFFFFF` If you apply `NEG` to both halves you get `0x00000001 0x00000001` which is clearly wrong. You need to apply the general rule of flipping all the bits and adding one, for example:

```
not ecx
not edx
add ecx, 1
adc edx, 0
```

Furthermore, I assume the assignment just wants you to use `add` and `adc`, you don't have to handle carry yourself.

Answer (score 0):

OK, thanks to everyone who tried to help, I wanna hug all of you ^.^ So here's solution:

```
//1 num
mov eax, 0 //l
mov ebx, 0 //h
//2 num
mov ecx, 1 //l
mov edx, 0 //h
//2 num -> 2's complement
not ecx
not edx
add ecx, 1
adc edx, 0
//1 num + (- 2 num)
add eax, ecx
adc ebx, edx
```